DHCP is adding a route to the gateway: is it necessary?
My server is configured via DHCP using the following routes:
default via 10.10.10.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 10.10.10.2 metric 100 
10.10.10.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.10.10.2 metric 100 

The first route is clear: Considering the fact that my address is 10.10.10.1, all traffic should go through the gateway at 10.10.10.2 using the ens3 interface.
The second route says that traffic to 10.10.10.1 should use the ens3 interface.
This route looks like routes to the local network (example) which make sense because packets to the local network shouldn't go through the gateway.
However, in our case, the second route is only pointing toward one host, which is the gateway, so I would assume the first route is enough here.

What are the netmasks? From the question, it seems all addresses are /32, so yes, the route is necessary, else how the system will know which NIC to ask when searching for the gateway? In typical case (when the netmask is /30 or wider) the prefix route is added automatically and it takes the role of the "route to the gateway".

@NikitaKipriyanov To be fair, one can indeed uses the onlink flag in a indirect route...

@TomYan ok, can it be configured with DHCP?

After trying, this is in practice necessary: If the gateway is not reachable through the second route, it is impossible to configure the first route, we get the following error:
Error: nexthop has invalid gateway

